# Is it allowed to wear shirt with games, movies or cartoon character?

Tags: clothing, cartoon

There are question on same topic but they were focused on 'while praying'
I know that these types of clothes are not allowed while praying , **BUT** is it allowed to wear them casually and when not praying .